# Eliminar directorio y archivos con php

Tags: php

Tengo la ruta de mi archivo por ejemplo

/carpeta/uploads/prueba/archivo.pdf

Actualmente elimino el archivo con unlink, pero necesito eliminar el directorio llamado "prueba" solamente, osea debo eliminar el archivo que hay dentro y la carpeta que contiene dicho archivo, he visto que es con rmdir pero no se aplicarlo ya que yo solamente obtengo la ruta del archivo

Comment: Puedes extraer la carpeta quitando lo que esté después del último `/` (en tu ejemplo, archivo.pdf) y ya tienes la carpeta a borrar.

Answer (score 2):

Para eliminar directorios, se usa `rmdir`
Al cual le agregas la ruta del directorio a borrar.
Pero antes de ello, debes verificar que el directorio y el archivo existan, sino, arrojará errores.

```
if(file_exists("Ruta completa pdf")){
    unlink(pdf);
}

if(file_exists("Ruta completa a la carpeta")){
    rmdir(ruta carpeta);
}
```

Por otra parte, vale tener en cuenta si existen otros archivos o subdirectorios dentro de ese directorio. Para ello existen funciones que listan los archivos al interior. Pero creo que esto es un extra en lo que quieres.