# Como eliminar archivos y carpeta recursivamente con PHP

Tags: php, recursión

Hace unos días alguien preguntó sobre como eliminar toda una galería de imágenes y la carpeta contenedora con PHP. Por razones que no vienen al caso, la pregunta ya no existe.

El problema planteaba eliminar una carpeta o folder (en este caso es un álbum de imágenes o galería de un perfil/usuario) que dentro puede tener uno o varios archivos (para el caso imágenes) o más carpetas dentro. Algo similar a [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/405186/eliminar-directorio-y-archivos-con-php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo había preparado una respuesta con uno de mis Snippets que utilizo para tal fin. Usando [recursividad](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursi%C3%B3n_(ciencias_de_computaci%C3%B3n)) para eliminar todos (o ciertos) archivos dentro de la carpeta en cuestión.

```
<?php
    // Identificador de la carpeta, viene de la DB
    $folderID = '001';
    // Path Raíz donde estarían todos los archivos y carpetas
    $folderPath = 'images/'.$folderID;

    class helpers {
        public function delFolder($folderPath){
            // Comprobación si el directorio existe
            if (! is_dir($folderPath)) {
                echo 'Directorio <b>'.$folderPath."</b> no encontrado.";
            }
            else{
                /* Agregamos un / (slash, barra) al final, esto puede omitirse
                   si se concatena a la variable desde el inicio 
                   $folderID = '$id'.'/'; 
                */
                if (substr($folderPath, strlen($folderPath) - 1, 1) != '/'){
                    $folderPath .= '/';
                }
                // Marcamos todo, sin un tipo en particular
                $files = glob($folderPath . '*', GLOB_MARK);
                foreach ($files as $file) {
                    if (is_dir($file)) {
                        // Aca podemos listar, antes de borrar (debugg)
                        // echo $file.'<br>';

                        // Si es carpeta, hacemos recursividad
                        self::delFolder($file);
                    } else {
                        // Eliminamos los archivos
                        unlink($file);
                    }
                }
                // Eliminamos la carptera contenedora
                rmdir($folderPath);
            }
        }
    }

    // Instanciamos la clase
    $helper = new helpers();
    // Llamamos a nuestra función donde la necesitemos
    $helper->delFolder($folderPath);
```

El Snippet esta comentado y se entiende bastante bien, pero hay algo que es bueno recalcar, es el uso de [glob](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.glob.php). Con `glob` podemos buscar coincidencias de nombres de ruta con un patrón, y también podemos "marcar" que tipos de archivos podemos incluir en nuestra búsqueda. Por su parte `GLOB_MARK` es un **flag** que añade una barra a cada directorio devuelto.

Un ejemplo básico de `glob`

```
<?php
    foreach (glob("*.txt") as $fileName) {
        echo "Nombre: $fileName " . filesize($fileName) . "\n";
    }

    // Resultado 
    // Nombre: Songs.txt | Peso: 44686
    // Nombre: DataList.txt | Peso: 267625
    // Nombre: OCHOA.txt | Peso: 137820
```

Se que en la red existen muchos ejemplos de como hacer lo mismo de varias formas, pero creo que para tener una base (de aprendizaje) y saber los procesos de cada línea, mi Snippet anterior es bueno.

Igual alguien puede decir que se puede resumir en muchas menos líneas, pero repito creo que el propósito es el aprendizaje.

```
<?php
    function delFolder($folderPath) {
        $files = glob($folderPath . '/*');
        foreach ($files as $file) {
            is_dir($file) ? delFolder($file) : unlink($file);
        }
        rmdir($folderPath);
        return;
    }
```