# Metodo unlink para eliminar foto de carpeta local PHP por ID masivo

Tags: php, mysqli, join, inner

Saludos estoy trabajando en un codigo con el metodo UNLINK, el codigo
me funciona perfectamente, pero deja las foto en la carpeta local
cuando se elimina el album en general por ID

tengo una album de la cual estan en dos tablas (gallery_albums)
almacena nombres y fecha y (gallery_photos) almacena el id de
"gallery_album" y la ruta de la imagen.. el incoveniente es que el
codigo me funciona se elimina el album por medio de la album_id pero me deja las fotos¿? en la carpeta local "imagenes".. estoy hablando de un
album que puede tener mas de 30 fotos

```
CREATE TABLE `gallery_albums` ( `album_id` int(11) NOT NULL,  
`name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,

CREATE TABLE `gallery_photos` (   `photo_id` int(11) NOT NULL,  
`album_id` int(11) NOT NULL,`ruta` text COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT
NULL
```

el codigo que uso para eliminar

```
<li class="el-item"><a class="btn default btn-outline el-link" href="eliminar-album.php?album_id=<?php echo $row['album_id'];?>" onclick="return confirm('¿Estas seguro de eliminar? Esta accion no se puede deshacer');"><i class="mdi mdi-delete"></i></a></li>
```

y el formulario eliminar

```
    <?php
    
    require 'config/conexion.php'; 
    
    $album_id = $_GET['album_id'];
    
    $sql = "DELETE gallery_albums, gallery_photos FROM gallery_albums INNER JOIN gallery_photos ON gallery_albums.album_id = gallery_photos.album_id WHERE gallery_albums.album_id = $album_id";
            
    $resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);
    
    if($resultado) {
    
         unlink("imagenes/") ;   
      echo "Eliminado exitosamente";
      
    } else {
      echo "Error al eliminar";
      
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Hola Noveember, dentro de la carpeta `imagenes` ¿creas una carpeta para cada album o metes todas las fotos de todos los albums juntas?

Comment: @Marcos el dice esto: **el incoveniente es que el codigo me funciona se elimina el album por medio de la album_id pero me deja las fotos¿? en la carpeta local "imagenes"..** no le veo problema, solo quiere resolver el borrado de archivos y directorios

Comment: @ArcanisGK507, es que de la forma que lo plantea es muy probable que termine obteniendo respuestas donde le ofrezcan borrar todo el contenido del directorio y no creo que sea eso lo que esta necesitando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`unlink()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php) no hace eso y no me agrada `mysqli`, prefiero usar [`PDO`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo).

Para eliminar el contenido y los registro de la base de dato te dejo el siguiente ejemplo:

```
<?php
class AlbumManager {
    private $pdo;

    public function __construct($pdo) {
        $this->pdo = $pdo;
    }

    public function eliminarAlbumYFotos($album_id) {
        $sql = "SELECT ruta FROM gallery_photos WHERE album_id = :album_id";
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':album_id', $album_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        // Eliminamos las imagenes.
        foreach ($result as $row) {
            $rutaImagen = $row['ruta'];
            if (unlink($rutaImagen)) {
                echo "Imagen eliminada: $rutaImagen<br>";
            } else {
                echo "Error al eliminar la imagen: $rutaImagen<br>";
            }
        }


        $sqlDeletePhotos = "DELETE FROM gallery_photos WHERE album_id = :album_id";
        $stmtDeletePhotos = $this->pdo->prepare($sqlDeletePhotos);
        $stmtDeletePhotos->bindParam(':album_id', $album_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $resultadoDeletePhotos = $stmtDeletePhotos->execute();

        $sqlDeleteAlbum = "DELETE FROM gallery_albums WHERE album_id = :album_id";
        $stmtDeleteAlbum = $this->pdo->prepare($sqlDeleteAlbum);
        $stmtDeleteAlbum->bindParam(':album_id', $album_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $resultadoDeleteAlbum = $stmtDeleteAlbum->execute();

        if ($resultadoDeletePhotos && $resultadoDeleteAlbum) {
            echo "Álbum y todas las imágenes eliminados exitosamente";
        } else {
            echo "Error al eliminar el álbum";
        }
    }
}

// Configuración de la conexión PDO
$dsn = 'mysql:host=nombre_del_host;dbname=nombre_de_la_base_de_datos;charset=utf8';
$usuario = 'nombre_de_usuario';
$contraseña = 'contraseña';

try {
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $usuario, $contraseña);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $album_id = $_GET['album_id'];

    $albumManager = new AlbumManager($pdo);
    $albumManager->eliminarAlbumYFotos($album_id);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error de conexión: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

como podras ver simplemente le hago un bucle al resultado de la consulta de la base de datos y una vez que se eliminan entonces hago el borrado tomando en consideracion la relacion `album_id`

Comment: @Marcos tienes razon pero intentar hacer esto: unlink("imagenes/") ;  me deja ver que quier eliminar el albun con todo y archivos ... dejame verificar el post nuevamente y el codigo.

Comment: @Marcos, dentro de la carpeta imagenes se guardar las fotos, solo quiero eliminar las foto por medio de los ID relacionado no todas

Comment: entonces solo hay que quitar la linea de codigo que quita el directorio ... ya lo actualizo..

Comment: @Marcos ya hice los cambios.

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 me ha funcionado tu codigo! (Y)

Answer (score 1):

Creo que tu problema no viene de la query sino del proceso de eliminar los archivos.

Te recomiendo que uses [recursividad](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/600868/como-eliminar-archivos-y-carpeta-recursivamente-con-php) para poder eliminar todos los archivos y la carpeta que los contiene.

Te dejo este código pero puedes leer el link anterior para que veas la explicación completa. Aunque el código es bastante simple.

```
<?php
    // Identificador de la carpeta, viene de la DB
    $folderID = '001';
    // Path Raíz donde estarían todos los archivos y carpetas
    $folderPath = 'images/'.$folderID;

    class helpers {
        public function delFolder($folderPath){
            // Comprobación si el directorio existe
            if (! is_dir($folderPath)) {
                echo 'Directorio <b>'.$folderPath."</b> no encontrado.";
            }
            else{
                /* Agregamos un / (slash, barra) al final, esto puede omitirse
                   si se concatena a la variable desde el inicio 
                   $folderID = '$id'.'/'; 
                */
                if (substr($folderPath, strlen($folderPath) - 1, 1) != '/'){
                    $folderPath .= '/';
                }
                // Marcamos todo, sin un tipo en particular
                $files = glob($folderPath . '*', GLOB_MARK);
                foreach ($files as $file) {
                    if (is_dir($file)) {
                        // Aca podemos listar, antes de borrar (debugg)
                        // echo $file.'<br>';

                        // Si es carpeta, hacemos recursividad
                        self::delFolder($file);
                    } else {
                        // Eliminamos los archivos
                        unlink($file);
                    }
                }
                // Eliminamos la carptera contenedora
                rmdir($folderPath);
            }
        }
    }

    // Instanciamos la clase
    $helper = new helpers();
    // Llamamos a nuestra función donde la necesitemos
    $helper->delFolder($folderPath);
```